# Why stream average() method returns OptionalDouble instead of double?

Tags: java, java-stream, option-type

Today when I was writing code using stream average, I got to know that stream average returns `OptionalDouble` instead of `double`. I know why `OptionalDouble` is used for.

**What else can be returned when we call stream average so that we needed OptionalDouble?**

An example will really be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

My code is given below:

```
OptionalDouble average = persons.stream()
            .mapToInt(person -> person.getAge())
            .average();
if(average.isPresent()) {
    System.out.println(average.getAsDouble());
}
```

Here `persons` is an `ArrayList` of `Person` class.

Comment: so, what would be your solution to cover cases where the stream is empty?

Comment: Yep, I know, I don't need DoubleStream here actually. In my case, age will be always int.

Comment: @Mukit09 Actually what are you trying to achieve is the actual question here. Just find the average? What if the stream is empty?

Comment: yes, just find the average. Ok, if stream is empty, I thought 0.0 could be returned.

Comment: `double average = persons.stream().mapToDouble(person -> person.getAge()).average().orElse(0.0);`, but the answer to why is already answered by Aomine.

Comment: @Mukit09 Yes, indeed 0.0 could be returned. But that would be wrong. NaN would be a slightly better choice (sum/num = 0/0 = NaN, after all), but the solution they chose is the best so the user can decide what to do.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`OptionalDouble` is returned simply because the stream may be empty and it's a *really* good way to let the *user* decide what to do in the *"no value"* case i.e. you could provide an alternative value with `orElse`, perform another operation via `ifPresent`, throw an exception via `orElseThrow` etc.

Comment: if stream is empty, I thought 0.0 could be returned. Anyway got it now. :) Thanks

Comment: @Mukit09 why should the average of "nothing" be `0.0` would be my question then? clearly, the way they decided for is the correct one (in my opinion) - this ensures to handle all cases by application logic

Comment: If you want 0.0 as the average of no elements, just use `.orElse(0.0)`. I agree with @AKSW.

Comment: You can also call getAsDouble() if you really need as a double.

Comment: I'm just confused why there exists an `OptionalDouble` in the first place; wouldn't `Optional<Double>` be a better use of the generic type system and make a cleaner API?